# What is different between `row[3:]` and `row[3]` when I handle csv data file?

Tags: python, data-analysis

```
import csv
f = open('age.csv',encoding='utf8')
data = csv.reader(f)

for row in data :
    if '신도림' in row[0]:
        for i in row[3:]:
            print(i)
```

Hello, I just started python data analysis yesterday. csv file that I am using is about population survey based on ages and I got this question now.
When I use row[3] it gives me something like this

```
3
2
6
```

but when I use row[3:] it gives me the correct answer.

```
326
457
345
.
.
.
```

What is different between these two? Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is this:

`row[3]` is exactly one item (in this case, row):  the fourth item (since counting starts at zero).

`row[3:]` is a *range* of many items: from the fourth item in the list to the end of the sequence.

The `[<start-index>:<stop-index>:<step>]` syntax is shorthand for creating a [`slice` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice).  This slice object is a sort of generalized way to index many items in a sequence.

Comment: ah so that means 3: makes it goes to the end of  the item list! Thanks now I perfectly understand what gets me a wrong answer.

Comment: That’s great. If this answers your question, see this help page for how to update the question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers